# Script works at Wordpress back end but not at front end. Kindly assist

Tags: wordpress

Why is this script not working on my WordPress site front end? It works at the back end but not at the user end. Kindly assist.

HTML

```html
<input type="number" id="input-value" />
<input type="text" id="output-value" readonly />
```

JS

```js
var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#input-value").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value*250);
});
```

Comment: Does it show error or something else? Or output value ia wrong? Please provide more information.

Comment: No. It just won't work. It's suppose to auto update the input with id "ouput-value" by multiplying the number entered with 250. It does that at the backend but not at the front end. Kindly note that I use Elementor for my wordpress site and wrote the script in "Insert HTML Snippet" plugin , which I eventually pasted the shortcode on my Elementor wordpress page.

Comment: I have also tried other similarly working scripts, but the same thing happens. Works at backend but not at front end. I have also tried the "Ënhanced Text Editor" plugin to insert the script. But still the same result. Kindly assist me. This is the page link. https://yiolink.com/pay-electricity-bill/ . When the user enters an "Amount", it's supposed to auto update the "Service Charge".Thank you

Comment: At the moment, the question should already have something you tried to comment on, and what the result was. Could you revise the question more clearly? For a guide to the question, see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your code has been written in body of html and they ran before jQuery loads.

For solve this problem you should wrap your code with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Put your code here
});
```

Then your codes will run after all js libraries have been loaded.

Final code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $output = $("#output-value");
$("#amt5").keyup(function() {
    
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $output.val(value+250);
});

});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you Zed. Works Now.

Comment: I'll appreciate to click **Accept This Answer** tick. Thank you.